# Unknown Attribute - Attribute exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I am running in a quite confusing error.
 I'm trying to submit a Form with nested attributes - I'm whitelisting those via the strong_params in Rails 4.

Whenever I try to submit the Form, I'm getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute: email:

My User Model has the following setup:

#### user_controller.rb

```
def update
  if @user.profile.update_attributes!(profile_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to edit_user_path(@profile.user) }
    end
  end
end

private 

def profile_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email,
                               {:profile_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name, :website, :birthdate, :description,
                                 {:address_attributes => [:city, :country, :phone]}]}

  )
end
```

This gives me the following params:

> {"email"=>"martin@teachmeo.com",
>    "profile_attributes"=>
>     {"first_name"=>"Martin",
>      "last_name"=>"Lang",
>      "website"=>"",
>      "birthdate"=>"",
>      "description"=>""}}

My User Model looks the following:

> User(id: integer, email: string, password_digest: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, auth_token: string)

The Interesting thing is though, if I try to debug it via pry the @user.update_attributes(profile_params) works without any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling

```
@user.profile.update_attributes!(profile_params)
```

This means you're updating attributes on an instance of `Profile` *(I'll assume that's the model name)*, **not** `User`. As you've pointed out, `:email` is a column on the `User` model, **not** the `Profile` model. You're trying to apply a value for key `:email` to `@user.profile`, a column which `Profile` doesn't have, hence the `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute: email:` error.

I'm going to guess instead of the above you really want

```
@user.update_attributes!(profile_params)
```

since `User` has the `:email` attribute, and also likely has `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile` set.

Comment: D'oh.. Yes. makes perfect sense. 
I copied over the code from my Profile Controller after refactoring. Thank you!